# Joining Tables in Mysql Keeping Multiple Observations

Tags: mysql

I have table 1 and 2, and they can be joined on ID.  Any way I could achieve the final table?  Thanks!

Table 1:

```
ID ProcCode
1  a
2  b
```

Table 2:

```
ID DiagCode ICode
1  z        g
1  z        g
1  x        g
```

Final Table:

```
ID ProcCode DiagCode ICode
1  a        z        g
1  a        z        g
1  a        x        g
2  b        NULL     NULL
```

Comment: Where is the code for your first join?  Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like

```
select t1.ID, 
       t1.ProcCode, 
       t2.DiagCode, 
       t2.ICode
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```